# Enforce text truncation after UILabel resize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have `UILabel` that can be with various width during app runtime. The text in that `UILable` can be wider than the `UILabel` itself, so the text is sometimes truncated.

The problem is that the text isn't re-truncated after `UILabel` resize, so it is either wider than the `UILabel` or narrower.

How can I enforce the `UILabel` to re-truncate the text again to make it fit perfectly?

Comment: post some code, also what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think, I found a bug in my code. Will update later.

Answer (score 0):

To make the UILabel frame match the text you can use:

```
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

But then the UILabel might be too large for its container view (Controller's view or subview), in that case you might want to compute the text size and resize the label accordingly

```
CGSize labelSize = [messageText sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(myLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:myLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

To use this you need to set the numberOfLines of your label to 0;

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I actually had a bug at other place in my code, so the question is closed now.